# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials [ App ID does not match requested project. ]

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have tried to perform phone authentication using firebase,After putting the latest google-services.json file, the app was unable to generate OTP, It was throwing this error:

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials [ App ID does not match requested project. ]**

Comment: My problem is solved.  I Just delete my build folder, uninstall app from device and then run my project again, now its working fine succesfully connected with firebase.

Answer (score 4):

**My problem is solved.** I Just *delete my build folder*, uninstall app from device and then run my project again, now its working fine succesfully connected with firebase.

Comment: Seems that after adding google-services.json we need to clear build folder utterly as some settigs are cached there. Then on the fresh install flutter downloads dependencies again. That worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can check like this;

1. Open the terminal in project folders
2. In terminal : **cd android**
3. Then : **./gradlew signingReport**
4. Here you can compare firebase with sha-1 signatures.
5. If the signature here and the signature in firebase are different, update your signature in firebase.